# Is there a more efficient way to calculate the next line/column number from a multiline token?

Tags: f#

So I am working on constructing a lexer/parser pair using parser combinators which leaves me with some interesting problems. Now the specific problem this question is regarding I have actually solved but I am not completely happy with my solution.

```
module Program =            

    type Token = { value:string; line:int; column:int; }

    let lineTerminators = set ['\u000A'; '\u000D'; '\u2028'; '\u2029']

    let main () =

        let token = { value = "/*\r\n *\r\n *\r\n \n */"; line = 1; column = 1; }

        let chars = token.value.ToCharArray()

        let totalLines =
            chars
            |> Array.mapi(
                fun i c ->
                    if not (lineTerminators.Contains c)  then 
                        0 
                    else
                        if c <> '\n' || i = 0 || chars.[i - 1] <> '\r' then 
                            1 
                        else 
                            0
            )
            |> Array.sum

        let nextLine = token.line + totalLines

        let nextColumn =
            if totalLines = 0 then 
                token.column + token.value.Length 
            else
                1 + (chars 
                     |> Array.rev 
                     |> Array.findIndex lineTerminators.Contains)


        System.Console.ReadKey true |> ignore

    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your implementation is that it originally seems to expect that all line terminators are just single characters, but that's actually not the case - if you treat "\r\n" as a single line terminator (composed from 2 characters), then the situation should be more clear. For example, I would declare terminators like this:

```
let terminators = [ ['\r'; '\n']; ['\r']; ['\n'] ]
```

The order is significant - if we find "\r\n" first then we want to skip 2 characters (so that we don't count the next '\n' char as the next terminator). Unfortunately  *"skip 2 characters"* is a bit tricky - it cannot be done using `mapi` function, which calls the function for each element.

A direct implementation using a recursive function could look like this:

```
let input = "aaa\nbbb\r\nccc" |> List.ofSeq

// Returns Some() if input starts with token (and the returned
// value is the rest of the input with the starting token removed)
let rec equalStart input token = 
  match input, token with
  | _, [] -> Some(input) // End of recursion
  | a::input, b::token when a = b -> equalStart input token // Recursive call
  | _ -> None // Mismatch

// Counts the number of lines...
let rec countLines count input = 
  // Pick first terminator that matches with the beginning of the input (if any)
  let term = terminators |> List.tryPick (equalStart input)
  match term, input with 
  | None, _::input -> countLines count input  // Nothing found - continue
  | None, [] -> count + 1 // At the end, add the last line & return
  | Some(rest), _ -> countLines (count + 1) rest  // Found - add line & continue
```

If you were using some parser combinator library (such as [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/)), then you could use built-in parsers for most of the things. I didn't actually try this, but here is a rough sketch - you could store the list of terminators as a list of strings and generate parser for each of the string:

```
let terminators = [ "\r\n"; "\r"; "\n" ]
let parsers = [ for t in terminators -> 
                  parser { let! _ = pstring t  
                           return 1 } ] // Return '1' because we found next line
```

This gives you a list of parsers that return 1 when there is a terminator at the end - now you could aggregate all of them using `<|>` (or combinator) and then run the composed parser. If that fails, you can skip the first character (combine this with another parser) and continue recursively. The only problem is that parser combinators usually return all possible derivations ("\r\n" can be interpreted as two line breaks..), so you would need to get just the first result...

(From your question, it wasn't clear whether you actually want to use some parser combinator library or not, so I didn't elaborate on that topic - if you're interested, you can ask for more details...)

Comment: The problem is that in ECMAScript line terminators can have semantic meaning in certain contexts so I couldn't figure out a proper way to integrate line and column counts into the parser itself. To resolve this I apply a layer of code on top of the parser which keeps track of it. Now this layer also serves other purposes as well so it is not creating unnecessary cruft in my implementation. When I get home I'll try and add a bit more context to my question. Also my solution does actually work for `\r\n` with this condition `c <> '\n' || i = 0 || chars.[i - 1] <> '\r'`.

Comment: As to the parser combinator, I actually built it myself after reading that paper you linked me to and examining various implementations across the web *(Some good, some bad)*. All in all my implementation is a bit sparse but as I've run into issues I've added new features. There may be a clean way to implement line/column counts into the parser itself so maybe I should rework my question around that...

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Yes, I understood that your solution works - my thought was that you'd like to remove the explicit handling of the "\r\n" case. I too implemented my own (simple) combinators a couple of times - in that case, you can make sure that it accepts only the first case (on the other hand, FParsec could be more efficient etc..)

Comment: After reading your answer a couple times this will actually work quite well. *(It needs a few tweaks to get the next column but that will be simple enough.)* Let me save my parser combinator questions for another day. :)